# Check location every 15min even if app in foreground or killed state

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-workmanager, background-service, foreground-service

I have a requirement,  where my android app needs to check for location every 15 min and update it to SQLite DB. This process should happen even if app removed from background. I tried all the following ways, but none of them are working when app running for long time.

1. Runnable function with a foreground service. Below is the example

```
mHandlerTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doCheckLocation();
                mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, 60000 * 15);
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, 60000 * 15);
```

This is working fine, but if screen turned off that runnable is not triggering. I think it's because of doze mode.

2. Work manager with Periodic Work Request: This is also not triggering when device goes to doze mode / screen turned off.
3. Alarm Manager: This has few functions `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`, `setAlarmClock()` for triggering at exact time. But the battery consumption is very high and phone gets heated up if I'm using `setAlarmClock()`.

So I wanna try with a wake lock. When screen getting turned off I acquire it. I'll release it when screen is on. But wake lock is going to drain the battery, and most likely OS can kill my app.

Can anyone suggest a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: If the device is dozing it is, by definition, not moving.

Answer (score 0):

`WorkManager` and `AlarmManager` are in fact most efficient ways for scheduling some tasks in your app, but you just have requirements that aren't battery-efficient and won't be ever... both location tracking and "waking up" device every 15 minutes will cause high battery drain and I doubt you can prevent this